Compactness argument in Browder's proof of the change of variables theorem for multiple integrals
I'm reading Browder's proof of the change of variables theorem for multiple integrals, which begins with the following lemma:

I'm having trouble understanding the highlighted part. That is, I don't see why, given a diffeomorphism $\varphi \colon U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a compact set $K \subseteq U,$ for any fixed $\eta > 0$ one can find $\delta >0$ such that for all $\xi \in K$ the inequality $|\varphi(x) - T_\xi(x)| \leq \eta |x - \xi|$ holds for $x \in B(\xi, \delta)$. The problem is I don't know how to use compactness to show that the same $\delta$ works for every $\xi \in K.$
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
